# Material Node help from 2.7 to 3.4

Tags: materials

I am trying to use an old blend file for a project in blender 3.4. I have most of it working, but the material is not. In 2.7 there is a material geometry node with outputs for "view" and "orco". I cannot find an equivelent node in blender 3.4. Picture shows the two different setups.
[image]

Comment: Clue for 'Orco' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9303819/11419356) ,, seems to be a mapping of  'Generated'  from [0  ->  1] to [-1 -> 1 ]? Is 'View'  a variation of 'Camera' ±Z ?   Docs not incredible helpful ..https://ia800405.us.archive.org/24/items/BlenderWikiPDFManual/blender_wiki_pdf_manual_EN_20141110.pdf   Maybe an older-timer than me will turn up to answer you definitely

Comment: The simplest explanation, I think, is that the Geometry node has been re-worked (components moved into other nodes like Texture Coordinate, Camera Data, Object info, Point info, etc...) and therefore can no longer be calculated according to the new  node system. Also, the texture system was completely replaced by the new material shader system.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to use another shader one i found and do some tweaking.